# Change highlight point color in flot

Tags: flot

I am using latest flot plugin 0.8 to plot some realtime data.I stuck at following issue

I highlighted point using `plot.highlight(series, dataPoint);`

Its perfectly working fine.But now I want to change highlight color of already plotted graph.

Is there any way to change highlight point color  after plotting flot chart?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply change the series 'highlightColor' option, i.e.

```
plot.getData()[0].highlightColor = "#f00";
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @DNS..I just have one question I dont know whether it relates to this issue or not.Can we set different color for different highlighted point?

Comment: That should really be a separate question (if there isn't already one), but the answer is no, not within a single series.